# starting multiple x-sessions with different DE/WMs with startx in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, window-manager, xmonad, startx

I'm using Linux mint, and I want two windows managers (MATE and xmonad) running on different pipes. I installed xmonad, and when I choose xmonad from the login screen it works perfectly.

But, when I move to pipe tty1, login, and run `startx xmonad`, I get an error:

```
<home dir>/.xmonad/xmonad-i386-linux: executeFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

The screen is white, and pressing Alt-Shift-Enter opens a window for a split second then returns to the white screen.

Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: Check your `.xinitrc`.

Comment: @Mikel I don't have a `.xinitfile`. (running `find / -name .xinitrc 2> /dev/null` resulted with nothing.

Comment: To ask the obvious: does the xmonad file mentioned in the error message exist? Should it?

Comment: Do you see any other errors?  I would have expected you to need to add `-- :1` to your `startx` command if there is already an X server running on `:0`.

Comment: @Mikel it doesn't exist, but xmonad runs very nicely when I choose it from the login in screen. Adding `-- :1 doesn't change any thing.

Comment: This message is not exactly an error. It just means xmonad didn't find a personalized executable or an `xmonad.hs` file to compile, so it will start with the default configuration. If you aren't starting anything else, all you get is a black screen (use Alt+Shift+Enter to start an xterm). If this doesn't happen, do you have an error message ? Does X just terminate ?

Comment: @Leiaz when I don't have a `xmonad.hs` file I get the message above, when I have one I don't. Any way I get a white screen, and pressing Alt+Shift+Enter results with a window that shows for a moment and nothing else. Pressing Alt+J, Alt-k or Alt+Space doesn't do any thing I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must give the full path : `startx /usr/bin/xmonad`

What happens when you run `startx xmonad` is `xmonad` is treated like an argument for the default client : xterm. So `xterm xmonad` is ran.